# How to create an ObjectChangeListener with OpenLdap

Tags: jndi, openldap

I'm trying to use an ObjectChangeListener with an openldap connexion. 
I ve got the following java code

```
public class MyListener implements ObjectChangeListener
{
 // Here my class variable
 public MyListener (DirContext ldapContext, String myDn) throws InternalException
{
  try
  {
    // Make a new connection without pooling
     Hashtable env = new Hashtable(ldapContext.getEnvironment());
     // env is set by other classes : in our case we use the factory java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory

     InitialDirContext localContext = new InitialDirContext(env);

     //     Get the EventContext for registering the listener
     evtCtx = (EventContext) localContext.lookup("");
     localContext.close();  
     // Register the listener for namespace change events
     evtCtx.addNamingListener(myDn, EventContext.OBJECT_SCOPE, this);

  }
  catch (NamingException e)
  {
      throw new InternalException("Error while registering my listener");
  }
}
 //some methods
}
```

When I create a new MyListenerObject, i ve got the following error sent by my openLdap server.

javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 12 - critical extension is not recognized]; remaining name 'ou=MyOU,O=MyOrg'

I don't know what i need to do (or if it possible) to create an ObjectListener whith OpenLdap.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can't. OpenLDAP doesn't support it as of the current release (2.4).